# How can I pull values from a deserialized feed when its class isn't known at runtime?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson to deserialize feeds and pull specific values from it. I'm trying to do this without know what feeds will be selected at runtime. I attempted to make a generic class that contains the method for deserializing the feed, and it works oddly enough. The problem is I can't pull any information from it without explicitly stating which class I am pulling from.

```
public class Motor<T> {

    final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

    public Object pullJson( String url, Object blah ) throws IOException{

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T mapped = jsonMapper.readValue(new URL(url), (Class<T>) blah);

        return mapped;
    }

    //Some other code
}

public class Root{
    public static String value;

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}

public class Propeller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Motor<?> motor = new Motor();
        List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(Root.class)

        String url = "blah.com/blah.json"
        Object blah = classes.get(0);

        blah = motor.pullJson(url, blah);

        System.out.println(blah.value);
    }
}
```

The only way I could think to pass a class into the method without know what the class will be was to set the class parameter as an Object and then pass a generic class onto it.

If I we're to ask for Root.value, it'll give me value's value, but I won't know what class the method will act on at runtime. And trying to act on the class declared as blah will tell me value cannot be resolved. I have a feeling my thought process here is extremely flawed in trying to pass a class as an object and reading the values that way.

Comment: this sounds like you need Jackson @JsonAny###### explained here http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html.